# What executes first: ToggleButton.IsChecked binding update, or Command binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

First - a disclaimer:

> If you're reading this because you want to use both a binding for
>   IsChecked and a RelayCommand to change things, you probably are doing
>   it wrong. You should be working off of the `IsChecked` binding's
>   `Set()` call.

**The question:**

I have a ToggleButton in which there's both a binding for `IsChecked` and for a `Command`:

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding BooleanBackedProperty}" 
         Command="{Binding SomeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
         CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Yes - I know, tsk tsk. Couldn't be helped.

When the user clicks the ToggleButton, which these two is going to fire first? Is the Command going to be executed, or is the IsChecked binding going to update the bound property? Or - is this actually similar to the post on social [in which it creates a race condition](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0504655-c298-4ee1-85eb-f48a39742f61/togglebuttons-command?forum=wpf)?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET pointed out that the social.msdn post is "a little different I think [in that] there's a race condition between three commands".

Comment: Hi, what it is rationale behind this disclaimer? I have a situation when I want to separately control property value and an action. Checkbox does both things, but other parts of program want to do it independently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IsChecked` will have a valid value at the command run time.

`ToggleButton` overrides `OnClick` from `ButtonBase` like this:

```
    protected override void OnClick()
    {
        OnToggle();
        base.OnClick();
    }
```

`OnToggle` is the method that updates `IsChecked`:

```
    protected internal virtual void OnToggle()
    {
        // If IsChecked == true && IsThreeState == true   --->  IsChecked = null
        // If IsChecked == true && IsThreeState == false  --->  IsChecked = false
        // If IsChecked == false                          --->  IsChecked = true
        // If IsChecked == null                           --->  IsChecked = false
        bool? isChecked;
        if (IsChecked == true)
            isChecked = IsThreeState ? (bool?)null : (bool?)false;
        else // false or null
            isChecked = IsChecked.HasValue; // HasValue returns true if IsChecked==false
        SetCurrentValueInternal(IsCheckedProperty, isChecked);
    }
```

And the base `OnClick` fires the command:

```
    protected virtual void OnClick()
    {
        RoutedEventArgs newEvent = new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent, this);
        RaiseEvent(newEvent);

        MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.ExecuteCommandSource(this);
    }
```

Source: [MSDN Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Primitives/ToggleButton.cs,490b99387e5fd4e0)

So the value should be valid by the time the command runs.

Comment: Deleted my answer -- this is much more thorough.

Comment: FYI, Bradley - your MSDN Ref Source link ^ got busted :(

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Thanks, good thing I copied the code :) Link is fixed now